# Remove value from Object array without altering database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have the following code that is getting `customers` from the database. I parse it in order to display only values that contains a specific user within them. To do that, I want to suppress the useless ones from the variable. Problem is that the removed `customer` is also deleted from the database. How can I prevent this to happen?

```
cust = Customer.where("company LIKE :prefix", prefix: "#{prefix}%")

cust.each do |c|
  if c.contracts.where(user: user).nil?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are cool with MySQL, you could as well do a JOIN query with Customers and Contracts and fetch the ones which match your conditions.

Or, to keep it simple and stupid, you could loop/select on the actual result "cust" and create a new array. Loop on this new array and do whatever is intended.

> full_cust = Customer.where("company LIKE :prefix", prefix:
>   "#{prefix}%")
>
> cust = full_cust.select {|c| c if c.contracts.where(user: user).nil?}
>
> cust.each do |c|   # DO WHATEVER IS INTENDED end